# Android Edittext Using inputtype as Phone cannot use letter only numbers

Tags: android

In my Android application, I have a field where 95% off the time it's only numbers. 
So I set the inputtype of my edittext as "number" 
But I have some case where the user must enter char in the field Ex : AF1233636

In my case using the standard alpha numeric keyboard is a bad option because users must wear gloves.

So I found the inputype "phone" where there is number and chars but only numbers are working.

I cannot get char inside my fields only numbers

[image: Phone keyboard]

```
  <EditText
        android:id="@+id/fld_tag"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:cursorVisible="false"
        android:inputType="phone"
        android:digits="0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:maxLength="10"
        android:textStyle="bold" />
```

So when the user stay push on a number I want the char appear as it was working on old phone to write text.

Any idea ?

Answer (score 0):

Check out this tutorial for creating a custom IME https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/create-a-custom-keyboard-on-android--cms-22615 ... create something similar to this except with t9 functionality.  Those letters underneath the numbers are just for visualizing when typing in a phone style app.